# Matrices become same after any operator

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a class called BasePoint

```
BasePoint
{
public:
    BasePoint();
    //BasePoint(const BasePoint& bp);
    uint id;
    float avgVal;
    float varVal;
    float avgLas;
    float varLas;
    cv::Mat invariants;// Type : 32FC1
    int status;
};
```

and have 2 objects of this class:

```
BasePoint previousBasePoint;
BasePoint currentBasePoint;
```

In every iteration I perform

```
const float norm_factor = 1.0;
currentBasePoint.invariants = totalInvariants / norm_factor; // Problem is here
currentBasePoint.id = image_counter;

if(previousBasePoint.id == 0)
{
     previousBasePoint = currentBasePoint;
     currentPlace->members.push_back(currentBasePoint);
     wholebasepoints.push_back(currentBasePoint);
}
else
{
     //some code here
}
```

The problem with the code is that when I perform `totalInvariants / norm_factor;` instead of using `totalInvariants`, `previousBasePoint` become same with `currentBasePoint`. However, If I do not divide it everything works fine. What can be the problem here?

**EDIT:**

```
const float norm_factor = 1.0;
currentBasePoint.invariants = totalInvariants;
currentBasePoint.invariants = currenBasePoint.invariants / norm_factor
```

also works, but I am still wondering what is wrong with the division

Comment: How were your `cv::Mat` objects initialized?  Can you provide a [mcve] so anyone can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I have not initialized it. previousBasePoint and currentBasePoint are 2 objects in another class `PlaceDetector::PlaceDetector(){
private: 
BasePoint currentBasePoint 
BasePoint previousBasePoint; }`

Comment: the code in your edited part is not the same, you are doing a division on the currenBasePoint, not the invariants member of currentBasePoint (also there is a type on there). in the original code there is an assignment previousBasePoint = currentBasePoint as well.if your id is always 0 due to a faulty copy constructor or assignment operator than you would always copy your result into previousBasePoint

Comment: Edited part was wrong I corrected it. I update the previousBasePoint at the end of the loop at else part of the code but it gives the right answer, unless I dont divide currentBasePoint.invariants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by overloading = operator.

```
class A{
    public:
        cv::Mat matrix;
        A(){
            this->matrix = cv::Mat();
        }

        A(const A& otherA){
            std::cout << "Copy Called" << std::endl;
            this->matrix = otherA.matrix.clone();
        }

            void operator = (const A& otherA){
            std::cout << "Operator overlad called" << std::endl;
            this->matrix = otherA.matrix.clone();
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        A a1,a2;
        cv::Mat anotherMat = cv::Mat::ones(3,3,CV_32FC1);
        a1.matrix = cv::Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_32FC1);
        //        a2 = a1;
        a2 = a1;
        std::cout << a2.matrix << std::endl;
        a1.matrix = anotherMat / 5; // Division, type MatExpr
        std::cout << a2.matrix << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Output without operator overloading[1]:

```
[0, 0, 0;   [0.2, 0.2, 0.2;
 0, 0, 0;    0.2, 0.2, 0.2;
 0, 0, 0]    0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
```

Output with operator overloading[2]:

```
[0, 0, 0;   [0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0;    0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0]    0, 0, 0]
```

Output without division[3]:

```
[0, 0, 0;   [0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0;    0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0]    0, 0, 0]
```

In OpenCV documentation:

> C++: Mat& Mat::operator=(const Mat& m)
>
> C++: Mat& Mat::operator=(const MatExpr& expr)
>
> m – Assigned, right-hand-side matrix. Matrix assignment is an O(1)
>   operation. This means that no data is copied but the data is shared
>   and the reference counter, if any, is incremented. Before assigning
>   new data, the old data is de-referenced via Mat::release() .
>
> expr – Assigned matrix expression object. As opposite to the first
>   form of the assignment operation, the second form can reuse already
>   allocated matrix if it has the right size and type to fit the matrix
>   expression result. It is automatically handled by the real function
>   that the matrix expressions is expanded to. For example, C=A+B is
>   expanded to add(A, B, C), and add() takes care of automatic C
>   reallocation.

So this problem happens, since `/` operator returns `MatExpr` object and it causes that shared data can be reused by other matrix. But I expect that output[1] will be the same with output[3].

Answer (score 3):

You are using `=` opeartor on `cv::Mat` which uses a shallow copy operation. So all of them will have the same memory address, you need to use `clone()` operation of `cv::Mat`.

Also you need to overload = operator of `BasePoint` as default operator on `previousBasePoint = currentBasePoint;` will also do a shallow copy of the internal `invariant`.

Comment: But `=` operator is not the problem without `/norm_factor`. Also I defined copy instructor for `BasePoint` which clones invariants and overloads `=` operator.

Comment: I am currently out of ideas, there must be something else, are there any leaks, what is the result of `currentBasePoint.invariants = totalInvariants.clone() / norm_factor;`?

Comment: It is same with `currentBasePoint.invariants = totalInvariants.clone() / norm_factor;` since it returns MatExpr object. I solved the problem and explained in detail